# Is the Living Gem the Calimemnon Crystal?

Tags: lore, forgotten-realms, artifacts

Page 20 of the AD&D 2e book *Running the Realms* describes the item found by Shond Tarovin known as the Living Gem:

> In Schamedar (Calimshan), the adventurer-wizard Shond Tharovin has
>   announced his discovery (in the ruins found in the Forest of Mir) of a
>   glowing, faceted ruby as large as a human's head. He found the stone
>   floating in midair in a shattered underground temple, and believes it
>   to be the stone known in ancient texts as the Living Gem. It flies
>   about at his command, and Shond Tharovin has taken it to meetings with
>   the local ruling council.

Is this gem the same as the Calimemnon Crystal described in page 13 of the [*Empires of the Shining Sea*](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/17533/Empires-of-the-Shining-Sea-2e) book? If not, is this described in any other official source?

P.S.: All the books cited here are from 2e, but I am interested in official description from any edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No. They are not the same. Detailed info on the Living Gem is available in VGtATM.

The Living Gem is described in *Volo's Guide to All Things Magical* (VGtATM) [pages 110-111]. Its history dates back 8000 years to the lands that would eventually become Calimshan. So the rough date and location of origin seem to match with the history of the Calimemnon Crystal. Moreover the backstories of both the Living Gem and the Calimemnon Crystal have genies, and other elemental creatures involved, so an imaginative DM could entertain the idea that they are the same thing.

Yet, the details of the artifact's powers described in VGtATM do not match the information about the Calimemnon Crystal. Moreover, we know from VGtATM, as well as from its mention in *Demihuman Deities* [page 20], that the location of the Living Gem was some sort of temple in the Forest of Mir. On the other hand, according to the *Lost Empires of Faerûn* [page 124], the Calimemnon Crystal was housed from its creation onwards at the [Spinning Keep of Siri'wadjen](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Spinning_Keep_of_Siri%27wadjen), which was a magical structure floating above the Calim Desert. So the two cannot be the same.